# Google Directions Service não contabiliza requisições feitas com minha api key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou utilizando a mesma referência de javascript tanto para utilizar o directions service quando o maps api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MINHA_CHAVE"></script>
```

As requisições feitas para a api do maps estão sendo contabilizadas normalmente. Cada vez que eu abro uma tela que carrega o maps, o contador no google developer console é incrementado instantaneamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que as requisições feitas para a api directions (directionsService.route()) estão funcionando normalmente mas não são contabilizadas.

Imagino que isso possa causar problemas futuramente caso eu exceda o limite e não pague... talvez o servidor seja bloqueado.

Obs. Ainda não ativei billing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, já descobri o porquê dos chamados a route() não contabilizarem. 
Esse DirectionsService que estou usando é a versão embutida dentro do Maps Javascript API, então está sujeito apenas a limitação desse serviço que é de 25.000 map loads por dia, ou seja, abrir um mapa do google 25000 vezes, independente de zoom, navegar no mapa, etc... só conta o load do mapa.

Fora isso, a única limitação do DirectionsServices dentro da api javascript é de chamadas por segundo. As primeiras dez chamadas podem ser dentro de um segundo, porém, as subsequentes deverão aguardar um período maior entre uma chamada e outra e caso você tente fazer a requisição em um intervalo muito curto receberá o status de erro 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'. O maior delay necessário chega a um segundo pelos meus testes.

Para número de chamadas por dia ou por mês não existe limite no uso do DirectionsService.route(), por isso ele não é contabilizado no gerenciador de cotas do google developer console.